# Can we have the [kony] tag renamed?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

The company [Kony Inc.](https://www.kony.com/), which fathered the tech stack to which the [kony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kony) tag refers to, was acquired by [Temenos](https://www.temenos.com/) in Sept 2019.

- https://www.temenos.com/news/2019/09/25/temenos-completes-acquisition-of-kony/
- https://www.businesswire.com/news/home/20190828005602/en/Temenos-Acquire-Kony-1-Digital-Banking-SaaS

As a result, the tag name is no longer accurate.

Moving forward, the technology stack is retaining its original name though: [***"Quantum"***](https://www.kony.com/products/quantum/).

Ergo, it would be ideal if we can get this [kony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kony) tag renamed to `temenos-quantum`, and then create a "kony" synonym for it, just for the sake of helping others find it by its original name.

Comment: What about Kony DBX?

Comment: As far as I know, company names are not valid tag names to begin with.

Comment: `kony` should just be renamed to `quantum` if it solely refers to the technology stack. No need to mention its owner in the tag name. That way, when it gets sold in 6 months, we don't have to do this again ;).

Comment: I had a look at some tag names before suggesting this. There's *a ton* of other tags prefixed with company names, such as `oracle-`, `ibm-`, `microsoft-`. There's also [several software products](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=quantum+software&t=ffab&atb=v176-1&ia=web) out there named "Quantum", so I'm thinking that just `quantum` would be very ambiguous. However, I'll settle for `quantum` if the moderators feel it's sufficient.

Answer (score 4):

I've renamed the [kony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kony) tag to [temenos-quantum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/temenos-quantum) (and also created a synonym, so as not to break any bookmarks).

While I agree with others' point that we prefer not to have the company name in our tags, I feel that the name of the product ("Quantum", in this case) is just too generic. If we went with a [quantum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quantum) tag, you'd constantly be fighting incorrectly tagged questions about "quantum computing" and the TensorFlow Quantum product.

Now, I need you to [update the tag wiki and excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/temenos-quantum/info) for the [temenos-quantum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/temenos-quantum) tag!

Comment: Sure thing @CodyGray . I'll do that. Thank you.